# Retrieve built-in UI sprites via code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resources

There are about 7 Sprites included in Unity that are used when you create a UI. I want to access these through code.These include the UISprite, UIMask, Knob, Background and others as circled in the screenshot below.

[image]

I dug deep in the UI source code and found all their location declared in the [`MenuOptions.cs`](https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/src/6a975b5d7ec71f5cf99b615bc31d1d14e6e246db/UnityEditor.UI/UI/MenuOptions.cs?at=2017.1&fileviewer=file-view-default) script.

```
private const string kStandardSpritePath = "UI/Skin/UISprite.psd";
private const string kBackgroundSpritePath = "UI/Skin/Background.psd";
private const string kInputFieldBackgroundPath = "UI/Skin/InputFieldBackground.psd";
private const string kKnobPath = "UI/Skin/Knob.psd";
private const string kCheckmarkPath = "UI/Skin/Checkmark.psd";
private const string kDropdownArrowPath = "UI/Skin/DropdownArrow.psd";
private const string kMaskPath = "UI/Skin/UIMask.psd";
```

In the Editor I was able to retrieve them with the GetBuiltinExtraResource function:

```
Sprite img = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource<Sprite>("UI/Skin/InputFieldBackground.psd");
Debug.Log(img); //NOT NULL
```

Unfortunately, `AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource` is from the `UnityEditor` namespace and will not work in a build or standalone program. It can't even compile.

---

I tried to use `Resources.GetBuiltinResource` for the build and standalone but it always returns `null`. It cannot find the built-in sprites.

```
UnityEngine.Object img = Resources.GetBuiltinResource(typeof(UnityEngine.Object), "UI/Skin/InputFieldBackground.psd");
Debug.Log(img); NULL
```

Tried `typeof(Sprite)` instead of `typeof(UnityEngine.Object)` but that failed too.

How can one access these build-in sprites in a standalone build instead of the Editor?

**Note**:

*I do not want to use a prefab or public variable to do this which requires doing stuff manually first. This is the current way I am already doing it. I just want to access the built-in sprites that are already packaged in the build.*

Comment: I would say since after one day no one has been able to help, the manual way should be considered. Easy would be to have some manager in which you drag the sprites so you have references to them. Turn this into a prefab and its a one time drag per project. Then you can get them by code with SpriteManager.Instance.UISprite.

Comment: @Programmer, when going for the "Resources.GetBuiltinResource", are you positive that those sprites are included in your build?

Comment: @Hristo Yes, they are the default images included in Unity. They should be included in the build. It can also find the default materials but not those images.

Comment: @Everts that's how I am  doing it now but I asked this to see if anyone have ever figured out how to do it dynamically with `Resources.GetBuiltinResource`. This is for a plugin I am making that reuires those images and I don't want the user to have to do any extra step.

Comment: You know how Unity discards unused assets. It may be that your sprites are not packed if there is no explicit reference to them. You'd be better packing them in a folder that goes in Resources so you sure they are there and know where to get them in code. User won't have to do anything.

Comment: @Everts That is exactly what I meant to say with my comment.

Comment: @Everts I know it discards unused assets. *I will re-do my tests again today with the all the Images being used in the Editor to see if that's the issue*. Although, I've made so much progress in this. Grab `unity_builtin_extra` from `<UnityInstallPath>\Unity\Editor\Data\Resources` folder. It doesn't have an extension. Add `.asset` as the extension of the `unity_builtin_extra` file and drag it to your project. You will see a complete list of all those files I want to access.

Answer (score 0):

ummm... just make copies. theres only seven files, copy them to a Resources/Textures (make it if you have to) then just call them with:

```
Sprite knob = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Textures/Knob.psd") as Sprite;
```

this would be the easy way.. but for fun lets look at this

```
static void CreateMaterial()
{
    // Create a simple material asset

    Material material = new Material(Shader.Find("Specular"));
    AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(material, "Assets/MyMaterial.mat");

    // Add an animation clip to it
    AnimationClip animationClip = new AnimationClip();
    animationClip.name = "My Clip";
    AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(animationClip, material);

    // Reimport the asset after adding an object.
    // Otherwise the change only shows up when saving the project
    AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(animationClip));

    // Print the path of the created asset
    Debug.Log(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(material));
}
```

i found it in the unity docs. now i know its talking about a material... but it seems to me you could manually add the Sprites in question to your assets, so it ensures they are referenced and will be included in the build.

Comment: I would avoid copying them because if it's referenced by the user, there be duplicate of this file when Unity is building it

Comment: yep thats the easy way, not the right way, best would be to use `AssetDatabase.CreateAsset` you could always rig a button to `AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath());` one of the pics in question, then build and deploy and hit the button, this way you can ensure it is getting added to your assets when unity builds, and not getting stripped out.

Comment: or you it will crash and burn if for some reason the file isn't getting added.

Comment: Sorry but not sure what you mean by "rig a button"

Comment: `OnGUI(){ if(GUI.Button(new Rect(5,5,100,40),"CheckForFile")){                     //you will need to adjust the path to where you want to check for your asset.                                                 AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath());    };`         you can try/catch for debug purposes, but its kind of redundant since  a null pointer here tells you what you need to know

Comment: just a dummy button you can delete once you test to see if your files are getting added to the build. add the button, build, and click the button while deployed, if the asset is included nothing will happen, but if unity is stripping it out you will get an error, basically this is just to check to make sure the file exists in your deployment.

Comment: Note that the Sprites I am talking about is used with the new UI system(uGUI) not Unity's old UI System IMGUI. `OnGUI` or `GUI.Button` is the old UI system that doesn't use the Sprites I mentioned in this question. Using them wouldn't cause the Sprites to be included in the build....

Comment: i dont suggest you keep the button, just use it for a quick debug to see if the files are there in your build. but no worries,  im interested to see what you do for a fix!

Comment: you could just as easily call `AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath()); ` from a button on a canvas, or set a timer and just call it once your loaded.

Comment: Sorry if I sound like I am not helping but AssetDatabase is from the UnityEditor namespace which cannot be used in a build. So I can't use it when the game has loaded

Comment: I have yet to try this but have u seen https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Build.Reporting.BuildReport.html. It will tell you everything that happens during your build, what files get added, and there's a report for items that are stripped out.

Comment: Someone already commented about the Sprites being stripped out but I have verified that's not the issue by creating a dummy UI object that references the built-in Sprites I want to access during run-time. The file is there. It's just that I can't access it. I want to be able to access it without making a copy of it. I believe  this is some kind of bug and will file for a report when I have time. It should be able to work with `Resources.GetBuiltinResource` but it doesn't. The `AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource` works but for Editor only. Can't be used in a build.

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/loading-built-in-unity-resources.479206/) and [here](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Show_Built_In_Resources)

the first link has the code for a solution for you, the second is the built-in resources wiki on the unity site, which has a special class for the editor, to find the ACTUAL paths of the textures your needing. I know this is not a complete answer, but i feel its more than enough for  you... good luck and let me know!

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Both links you provided in the answer are using Editor API which works in the Editor only. These APIs will can only be used in the Editor like `AssetDatabase.GetBuiltinExtraResource` which I mentioned in my question. It can't be used in a build. It won't even build because you can't use it in a build. The equivalent build version of the API is `Resources.GetBuiltinResource` but it doesn't work so I am looking for why it doesn't work and how to access the built in resources without using a public variable or making copies of them.

Answer (score 0):

I also face the problem that the Button I create in script is different from the Button created in Unity Editor because I fail to retrieve the Unity build-in resources.But I make a **prefab** in Editor and load it into a GameObject in runtime to solve this problem.Now it passes!